# Using jquery how to drop down a menu items on-click?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, jquery-ui-accordion

In One of my webpage i need to show a side-menu it want to drop-down when user click it how to achieve it using jquery

Comment: look at the right menu here in SO under 'Related'

Comment: @all : Question asked on **02-Feb-2012** and down voted on **07-Aug-2014**

Comment: That's most probably cause does not fit the expected Q&A format. It should be actually closed.

Comment: Actually it would be even greater (even if 2y later) to see a good looking updated question. You can even answer your own question and -> accept your own answer. If it's better than the already answered one. Keep in mind to add freshness and great info in your answers! Thumbs up and please notify me if something like that occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a single level drop-down, then there are many ways to achieve this, using the `.fadeIn()` / `.fadeOut()` or `.show()` / `.hide()` works great for showing and hiding objects, such as dropdown content.

Of course you would have to design the dropdown content, then position it, then hide it using `display:none;` etc, then the opener can use $('#dropdowncontent').fadeIn(); to display it on `.hover()` and to hide it (using `.fadeOut()`) on `.blur()` or `.mouseout()`

Or you can look for add-ons that handle this as well here:
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/38-jquery-and-css-drop-down-multi-level-menu-solutions/

There are some great multi-level menu options in this link as well, hope this helps.